# Difference between packet loss and ACK loss

Tags: protocol-theory

I want to ask a question that seems to confuse me. I have a question in my self-study "Computer Networking" book which distinguishes a packet error from ACK error for a Selective Repeat protocol and for Go-Back-N.

To my knowledge the repetition will still make a timeout happen since a faulty ACK is still not understood so that wouldn't make a difference in behavior. That is it will retransmit.

Am I missing something or is the question deliberately making me confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, dependin upon the implementation protocol such as selective repeat or go-back N, will result in re-transmission. However ack and data packet are completely different entities. 
1. loss of ack will cause a re transmit because the timer at the sender will expire and force the client to send again. However the receiver already has this packet, and needs to discard the packet as duplicate. If the data packet it self was lost, re transmission would still occur but this time the receiver actually does not have a packet. Both deal with expiration of a timer, so you migh have been confused. But ack and data packet have completely different use. Later when you study the TCP protocol you will see that data packet consumes a sequence number while ack packet does not.

So both cannot be generalized as one.